# Argument needs to be of the class StMoMoData

Tags: r, modeling

Hi I'm going by the steps in [this file](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/StMoMo/vignettes/StMoMoVignette.pdf) to fit a CBD Model to US Male data, sourced from the HMD. Currently I have the error that my argument data is not of the class StMoMoData.

```
CBDfit <- fit(CBD, data = USData, ages.fit = 60:89)
Error in fit.StMoMo(CBD, data = USData, ages.fit = 60:89) : 
  Argument data needs to be of class StMoMoData.
```

I have tried downloading the HMD data straight from R using the demography package. I have also tried saving the HMD data as a .csv file and reading that into R. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function in the package to create objects of class StMoMoData. The function is `StMoMoData`... This is how to use it:

```
StMoMoData(data, series = names(data$rate)[1], type = c("central", "initial"))
```

Take a look in the documentation to learn further.. It's difficult to help you more, since you didn't provide a reproducible example or a bit of your code... But there is an example in the documentation:

```
library(demography)
NZdata <- hmd.mx(country = "NZL_NP", username = username, password = password, 
label = "New Zealand")
NZStMoMo <- StMoMoData(NZdata, series = "male")
summary(NZStMoMo)
```